# How do I acquire data from a NSNotification object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsnotification

I am trying to send a location update with the new location as a notification object.  When I do, I receive a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error when I try to access the data from the notification.  If I execute "po location" I see the data, but it is unclear to me why I cannot acquire it.  When setting the observer, I also tried assigning the object parameter to a member variable, but then locationUpdate is never called.

Here's my code (note that ARC is enabled):

// LocationController.h

```
@protocol LocationDelegateProtocol
@required
    - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

@interface LocationController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    id delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, strong) id delegate;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

+ (LocationController *)sharedInstance; // this class is a singleton

@end
```

// LocationController.m

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [Notification locationChanged:newLocation];
}
```

// Notification.h

```
@interface Notification : NSObject
    + (void)locationChanged:(CLLocation *)newLocation;
@end

extern NSString *const kLocationChanged;
```

// Notification.m

```
NSString *const kLocationChanged = @"NewLocation";

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLocationChanged object:newLocation];
```

// ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LocationDelegateProtocol> {
    ...
}
...
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;

@end
```

// ViewController.m

```
- (void)setupNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(locationUpdate:) name:kLocationChanged object:nil];
    // I've tried setting object to a member var "CLLocation *objectFromNotification", but then locationUpdate() is never called.
}

- (void)locationUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {    
    CLLocation *location = (CLLocation *) [notification object];
    // program receives signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when executing NSLog below.  I can see data inside location when I execute "po location".
    NSLog(@"latitude = %@, longitude = %@",location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the format specifier in your NSLog from %@ to %f. You are trying to access float value as object!

Comment: LOL.  I had %f to start, but I had other defects and was playing around with classes.  After fixing some other defects I forgot to change it back.  I had assumed I didn't fix the original problem, which I did.  Thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it happens that we miss out small things.

Answer (score 2):

`NSNotifications` have a dictionary with them called `userInfo` where you can put information you want to be sent with the notification.

I am going to fix your code kinda going backwards,  so bear with me. You really haven't used the NSNotification class as it is typically (or intended to be) used.

To fix this situation, we have to do a bunch of things. The `object` value of an `NSNotification` post is the object that is posting the `NSNotification`, not the object you want to pass with it.

Add the `CLLocation` object to a dictionary, and pass it in as the `userInfo` dictionary. There is also no reason for this custom notification class stuff you have. So you can get rid of the `Notification.h` and `Notification.m`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSString *const kLocationChanged = @"NewLocation";
    NSDictionary *locationDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:newLocation forKey:@"Location"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLocationChanged object:nil userInfo:locationDict];
}
```

So now we are posting the location information with the notification. Next, handle it when you get the notification.

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {    
    CLLocation *location = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"Location"];

    NSLog(@"latitude = %f, longitude = %f",location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Also, change your view controller header to the following:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LocationDelegateProtocol> {
    ...
}
...
- (void)locationUpdate:(NSNotification *)notif;

@end
```

Comment: My interpretation of the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html is that it is acceptable: "The object is any object that the poster of the notification wants to send to observers of that notification"

Comment: Indeed, you can do anything you want, thats the benefit of being the programmer. The problem with your current implementation arises when you need more information, multiple pieces of information, or you need to know what object sent the notification. The next line from the same documentation: "The object is any object that the poster of the notification wants to send to observers of that notification (typically, it is the object that posted the notification). The dictionary stores other related objects, if any."